# Get data of all childs of Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database with a child as `users`. This contains two users as `user1` and `user2`. Each of them contain `name` and `address`. Now I need to get the value of `name` and `address` of `user1` and `user2`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DatabaseReference ref1= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  DatabaseReference ref2;    
   ref2 = ref1.child("users");


   ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Userlist = new ArrayList<String>();                

        // Result will be holded Here
        for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Userlist.add(String.valueOf(dsp.geValue())); //add result into array list


        }
```